# how to change a message in sql server 2008 for a custom message?

Tags: sql-server-2008

how to change a message sql server for a personalized message, for example change the message: The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'AFRPTInformedeIngresosenCaja', database 'DBSIIEDesarr', schema 'dbo'. 
I want to be shown: "You do not have permission assigned to run this task"

Comment: Do you mean you want to globally override the error message that SQL Server returns at a database or server level? Usually you just intercept/scrub SQL errors in you application layer.

Answer (score 0):

Citing from the documentation for [sp_altermessage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175094%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> Alters the state of user-defined or system messages in an instance of
>   the SQL Server Database Engine. Messages can be viewed using the
>   sys.messages catalog view.

Whether it's a good idea to alter predefined system messages I don't know. You can also add new custom messages using [sp_addmessage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178649%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and have your calling application use [RAISERROR](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177497%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to trigger the custom message; it might be better to do this instead of changing the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in a TRY/CATCH block.  You could add IF statements for specific errors and specific messages.

```
BEGIN TRY
  EXEC foo
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  PRINT 'That did not work.'
END CATCH
```